# Including ActionController::Live breaks existing AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html

I have a controller with multiple actions/views, only one of which will take advantage of the `ActionController::Live` module.  However, once included, AJAX actions (on unrelated pages) no longer render on the client at all.

The following code works without a problem:

**my_controller.rb:**

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    def index
        // renders vanilla HTML/JS from index.html.erb
    end

    def update_index
        // renders JavaScript from index.js.erb
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb:**

```
<%= button_to({ controller: :my_controller, action: :update_index},
            remote: true,
            method: 'post') do %>
    Update the text
<% end %> 

<div id='content'>Some content</div>
```

**update_index.js.erb:**

```
$('#content').html('You clicked the button.');
```

**The Problem:**
As soon as I add `include ActionController::Live` to the controller, before even creating any JavaScript or Rails handles for Server Side Events (which work great), my existing code stops working.  The following occurs:

- Server sees the incoming AJAX request
- All appropriate Controller functions are called
- The JavaScript is not executed on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you've included `ActionController::Live` in your controller, it seems to change the default header situation on returns to the client.  Adding the following line to my non-SSE actions seemed to solve the problem:

```
response.headers["Content-Type"] = 'text/javascript'
```

But would love to hear if there's a better solution, or if I should just do this on all appropriate actions.